# Migrate v5 dynamic forms to v6.0.0-rc.4

Tags: redux-form

I knew how to do dynamic forms in v5, but now in v6 I'm stumped, since the `form` must be hardcoded & passed into the HOC.

Say I had a todo list, and I wanted each item to be its own form with a single field. In v5, I'd name the form dynamically, but I can't here since the HOC takes a static string and I can't inject anything dynamically.

Would I just treat it like 1 big form & then parse out the single item that I want from the `submittedData`? Is this where I use FieldArray? I have to initialize the data, and it seems weird to reinitialize the entire form for every Field in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `form` can be passed as a prop in `v6`, too.

```
handleSubmit(row) {
  return values => {
    // do something with values for this row
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.myData.map(row =>
        <RowForm 
          key={row.id} 
          form={`rowForm_${row.id}`} // unique form for each row
          initialValues={row}
          onSubmit={this.handleSubmit(row)}/>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Actually, the above pattern works well with both `v5` and `v6`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the best solution, but I created a HOC that calls reduxForm inside the render function. Now I can pass `formOptions` as a prop. Then, I make sure to only render it once. Additionally, I thought it'd be a good place for the initialization logic, so I stuck that in there, too.

```
export default ComposedComponent => {
  return class DynamicForm extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
      const {dispatch, formOptions: {form}, content} = this.props;
      dispatch(initialize(form, {outcomeCard: content}));
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate() {
      return false;
    }

    render() {
      const {formOptions, ...otherProps} = this.props;
      const WrappedComponent = reduxForm(formOptions)(ComposedComponent);
      return <WrappedComponent {...otherProps}/>;
    }
  }
};
```

Would love to see other ideas!